# CME error: Item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' with id 'Tridioncm_DEVSQLCMSDSQL2016CMSD' does not exist

Tags: content-manager, web8.5, topology-manager, powershell, publication

Trying to set a Publication Mapping on the Publication Properties in the CME I get this error:

```
Item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' with id 'Tridioncm_DEVSQLCMSDSQL2016CMSD' does not exist.
An error occurred while processing this request.
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TTM.TopologyMappingsImpl.UpdateMappings(XmlDocument mappingsXml)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtenderPublication.HandlePostSaveItem(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.ProcessGetItemResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.DataExtenders.CMEExtender.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ProcessResponse>b__0(DataExtender extender)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderParameterInspector.AfterCall(String operationName, Object[] outputs, Object& returnValue, Object correlationState)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
Hide Details
```

Perhaps the CME tries to lookup a `TtmCmEnvironment` which does not exitst. Earlier I removed the `TtmCmEnvironment` with the ID mentioned in the error message, and created a new one with a differnet name.

Can I configure the CM environment ID in the CM somewhere (I mean, other than in the Topology Manager)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is stored in the Windows Environment variable `TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID`.

```
 # you can set it with PowerShell
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID", "Development", "Machine")
```

Did you know there are a few more environment variables for SDL Web?

```
# you can inspect it with PowerShell
[cm-server]: PS C:\Users\jan\Documents> get-item env:tridion*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TRIDION_HOME                   C:\SDLWeb\
TRIDION_CONFIGURATION_URL      http://localhost:80/webservices/Configuration/ReadService.svc
TRIDION_CM_HOME                C:\SDLWeb\
TRIDION_TTM_SERVICEURL         http://localhost:81/ttm201601
TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID      Development
```